# Configuring server on Amazon S3 Bucket to redirect URLs

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with AngularjS. And i am using Amazon S3 Bucket.

I am trying to remove '#' from URLs of my website **which I did successfully**
Then i can across a problem where i was not able to reload any of the page from my website.
I received an error saying *cannot get filename* 
Then after some searching i came to know that i am supposed to **Rewrite URLs in server configuration** 
I found few links telling me about how to make such configurations. But i couldn't find any reference teaching me about making such configurations on **Amazon S3 Bucket**. 

How can i make configuration changes in this situation? Any useful reference/documentation for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewriting Amazon S3 static urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236472/rewriting-amazon-s3-static-urls)

Comment: You need to clarify the question.  S3 [can rewrite URLs, in one sense, using redirect rules](http://serverfault.com/a/633571/153161), but it is not possible that you are running Ruby on S3, so the nature of the problem is not clear and this question may be unrelated to S3.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is not a full-featured web application server like *nginx* or *Apache*. You cannot rewrite URLs. The only thing you can do with S3 bucket is handle error pages like 404.